# Facebook graph api log out not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph Api for Facebook authetication, I use following method for loging in.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, 
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {}];
```

This causes the log in page to be opened in mobile safari.I use   `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];` for loging out. My problem is i cant login back as a different user because the logout process doen't clear session in safari.

Same problem exists in the sample app provided in developer.facebook.com    http://cloud.github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.0.8.pkg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook app on iphone is usually meant for a single person , but when you test as developer you try to log in with different userid . Thats where the problem comes, before loggin into app u should first loggin fb app with the desired user id. 
It happens because fb api dnt let apps to make facebook app to signout. Every time user loggout from an app will make it fb signout also and that will be very annoying for the user.

Comment: then why they are providing a login functionality in sdk,if it for just signing out from app? is so what should i do to sign out from facebook?.In documentation it says that  "closeAndClearTokenInformation" will Closes the in-memory session, and clears any persisted cache related to the session.

Comment: signout function in api is for releasing the token your app has generated

Comment: okay, thank you for your reply.Do you have any idea about clearing cookies in safari from app?

Comment: NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies])
        {
            NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
            NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
            if(domainRange.length > 0)
            {
                [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
            }
        }

Comment: we cant delete cookies in safari like this from our app.This will work only for cookies set from webview of our app :(