# Close Facebook session in Facebook-Ios-Sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I close aCtive Session Of the `Facebook-iOS-Sdk` each time when i start my app either after killing app it gives me the previous login session details.  When I click on the facebook Button .I have used everything `[appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];`
      `[FBSession.activeSession close];` `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]` ..but active session still not been close..how do i close the Previous session data on clicking.

I use the below code to clear but whenever I click on the facebook button to start new session..it gives me back the previous credentials.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {

appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// this button's job is to flip-flop the session from open to closed
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    [FBSession.activeSession  closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    FBSession.activeSession=nil;

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    FBSession.activeSession=nil;
    [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                                FBSessionState state,

                                                NSError *error) {
                                // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state

                                NSLog(@" state=%d",state);

                                [FBRequestConnection
                                 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                                   NSError *error) {

                                     userInfo = @"";

                                     // Example: typed access (name)
                                     // - no special permissions required
                                     userInfo = user.username;

                                     NSLog(@"string %@", userInfo); 
                                          [self checkfacebook];

                                 }];


                            }];    } 


 }
```

and in **ViewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];





AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // create a fresh session object
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];


    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
        [FBSession.activeSession close];
        FBSession.activeSession=nil;
   }
}



NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}    


}
```

Answer (score 28):

hi Christien may be bellow two link its help's you please refur this two link of `developers.facebook`

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSession/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSession/#close

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

you can also check this two question related your issue :-

[Facebook graph api log out not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194876/facebook-graph-api-log-out-not-working)

[Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 "closeAndClearTokenInformation" method no working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896676/facebook-ios-sdk-3-1-1-closeandcleartokeninformation-method-no-working)

hope its helps you

Comment: ya thanks man ! I have tried all the thing but this weird thing happening again and again :( ...

Comment: This is indeed weird with fb api. I'm having same "problem". Btw, when you logout from facebook app (actual fb application on your device), then you are truly logged out. If you are logging out only in your app (not the fb one) you will get logged with sso with account you are using in your fb app...

Comment: for me also, its worked perfect!! great thanks to Mr.NitinGohel

Comment: I have used above 3 lines. It crashes in iOS8.

Answer (score 4):

After calling

```
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

use following to clear cookies. It worked for me!

```
     NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in
     [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: doesn't clear the old session when I click the login button. It always takes me to "You have already authorized appname" screen.

Comment: @SonnyG were you able to figure out solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nitin's Gohel answer, Swift version:

```
    FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
    FBSession.activeSession().close()
    FBSession.setActiveSession(FBSession())
```

you can use

```
    FBSession.setActiveSession(nil)
```

But the function ask for an unwrapped object, so "nil" seems not a good parameter to be pass